# Text element moves another element to the left

Tags: html, css, reactjs

My `h4` moves the `h3` to the left, any solution ideas?

```
<div className="pricing-card">
                    <h3 className="pricing-card-header starter">Starter</h3>
                    <h4 class="popular">Empfehlung</h4>
                    <div className="price">149<sup>€</sup></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><strong>5</strong> Seiten*</li>
                        <li><strong></strong> Individuelles Desing</li>
                        <li><strong></strong> Responsive (für alle Endgeräte)</li>
                        <li><strong></strong> Google Maps & Kontaktformular</li>
                        <li><strong></strong> Wartung & Support inklusive</li>
                        <li><strong></strong> Textänderungen inklusive</li>
                        <li><strong></strong> Suchmaschinenoptimiert (SEO)</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

I have tried many different things but they wont work
[a picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ4bo.png)

```
.pricing-card{
    flex: 1;
    max-width: auto;
    background: var(--card-bg);
    margin: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: var(--primary-color);
    transition: .3s linear;
}

.pricing-card-header {
    background-color: var(--btn-secondary-bg);
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: .4s linear;
}

.pricing-card:hover .pricing-card-header {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 36em var(--primary-color);
}

.popular {
    position: sticky;
    float: right !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 10px;
    left: 16rem;
    width: 4.8rem;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: var(--popular);
    color: var(--btn-secondary-bg);
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: What would be the desired output ? Keeping the h3 centered ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the width you are using on `.popular` is responsible for pushing your h3 to left. Try removing `width` under `popular` or set it to `auto`

Comment: i try it after i remove the width and have no changes